# Why doesn’t IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS increment @@TRANCOUNT for my IF statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transaction

I was playing around with `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON`. I found a situation where I am convinced the database is automatically creating and committing a transaction without leaving it open. If I do `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.t1)` or any variation, I am certain that a transaction is happening in the background which I’d expect to stay open if I’m using implicit transactions.

However, after reading [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql), it says something like:

> This means that if `@@TRANCOUNT = 0`, any of the following Transact-SQL statements begins a new transaction.

and the list it shows does not include `IF`. However, then I’d expect all statements not found in the documentation’s list to not leave `@@TRANCOUNT` incremented. So, I looked for another statement not included in that list. I found `DECLARE`. However, I found that if I perform a subquery with `DECLARE`, I get the behavior I’d expect from `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSATIONS ON`. That is, if my `DECLARE` has a subquery, it increments `@@TRANCOUNT` if it is zero. So it appears that the documentation is inconsistent with itself

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.t1') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE dbo.t1
    COMMIT
END
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.t1 (x INT);
COMMIT;
GO

IF CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.t1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1 PRINT 'unreachable';
PRINT 'after1 ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS VARCHAR(MAX)); -- after1 0

DECLARE @x INT = 2;
PRINT 'after2 ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS VARCHAR(MAX)); -- after2 0

DECLARE @y INT = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.t1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
PRINT 'after3 ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS VARCHAR(MAX)); -- after3 1
GO

WHILE @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK
GO
```

Why does `DECLARE` increment `@@TRANCOUNT` for an embedded `SELECT` but not `IF`? Is the `SELECT` embedded in the `IF` somehow not actually using a transaction?

I’m using SQL Server 13.0.4411.

Comment: Do you see the same behaviour if dbo.t1 contains any rows?

Comment: @GarethLyons Yes. All that changes if I insert a row is that [`PRINT 'unreachable'` is suddenly reachable ;-)](https://gist.github.com/binki/d7d597a1732a385809b4db824c057986).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that what you're seeing is because some statements get transformed to `SELECT` statements behind the scenes and others do not. Consider your final `DECLARE` statement:

```
DECLARE @y INT = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.t1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

That is just shorthand for this:

```
DECLARE @y INT;
SET @y = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.t1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Which can also be written like this:

```
DECLARE @y INT;
SELECT @y = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.t1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

In which case you'd expect to see `@@TRANCOUNT` incremented. However, can you make the same statement about the `IF` statement? If I run your original code with actual execution plans turned on I see the following:

[image: actual execution plan]

I don't see a `SELECT` in the plan for the first query. I only see `COND WITH QUERY`. So it seems consistent with the documentation.